# Не подключается шрифт

Tags: css, gulp

Подключаю шрифт, в папке с проектом имеет такой вид и на сайте он работает

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'alte_haas_groteskbold';
    src: url('../fonts/altehaasgroteskbold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/altehaasgroteskbold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

После того как собрал проект gulp`пом он имеет вид и шрифт на сайте не работает

```
    @font-face{
        font-family:alte_haas_groteskbold;
        src:url(../../fonts/altehaasgroteskbold-webfont.woff2) format('woff2'),
        url(../../fonts/altehaasgroteskbold-webfont.woff) format('woff');
        font-weight:400;
        font-style:normal
 }
```

Сам плагин gulp

```
var concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css');
let cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');

gulp.task('css', function () {
    return gulp.src('sourse/css/*.css')
        .pipe(concatCss("css/style.css"))
        .pipe(cleanCSS({
            compatibility: 'ie8'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('ready'));
});
```

В чем может быть проблема?

[image: До сборки]

[image: После сборки]

[image: Структура проекта]

Comment: В консоли какие ошибки? Скорее всего дело в правильном указании путей к шрифтам.

Comment: Добавил структуру проекта

Comment: Собранный `css` обращается к шрифтам `../../fonts/altehaasgroteskbold-webfont.woff`, сам посмотри куда это ведет. И поймешь почему не подключается

Comment: Пробовал `../fonts/altehaasgroteskbold-webfont.woff2) format('woff2')` тоже не работает, тем более на сайте шрифт отображается в стилях

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в неправильном названии папки *fonts* в папке *ready*. И нужно избавиться от лишнего "../" в font-face после сборки.